# uploading image in db2 with a servlet

Tags: servlets, jdbc, db2

i am trying to upload image into my db2 database.i have copied the libraries required
`db2jcc.jar` in `web-inf/lib`

```
<form action="Upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
ID : <input type="text" name="id"/><br>
FILE : <input type="file" name="photo"/><br>
<input type="submit" value="upload"/>
</form>
```

my uploader servlet is

```
try {
        String id=request.getParameter("id");
        Part photo =  request.getPart("photo");
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver").newInstance();
            Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:db2:SAMPLEDB");
            System.out.println("Connection Successful");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO SAMPLETABLE (ID,PHOTO) VALUES (?,?)");  
            ps.setString(1, id);
            File fBlob = new File ( request.getParameter("photo") );  //exception thrown here
            FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream ( fBlob );  
            ps.setBinaryStream (2, is, (int) fBlob.length() );  
            ps.execute ();  

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("exception --> "+e);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        out.close();
    }
}
```

the exception i am getting is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Answer (score 1):

The request.getParameter() and its related methods do not work with multi-part requests, and will always return null when dealing with multipart form data.

See the following on File Uploads in Java:
https://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/FileUpload

Here's even a better solution: http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/file_upload/Sinle_upload.xhtml.shtml

Comment: did wts dre in  roseindia.net...bt its not wrking...can any1 tl me d solution??????????